# XML Node extraction using Java

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling

Hi I need to extract the customer name element part in the XML String. How can I do it with Java. My purpose is to do unmarshall the xml to java object.

The following code is my response string. Can some body help me in extracting the customer element aloe from this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <control>
        <status>success</status>
        <senderid>XXXX</senderid>
        <controlid>ControlIdHere</controlid>
        <uniqueid>false</uniqueid>
        <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>
  </control>
  <operation>
        <authentication>
              <status>XXXX</status>
              <userid>XXXX</userid>
              <companyid>XXXXXX</companyid>
              <sessiontimestamp>2014-08-12T03:49:00-07:00</sessiontimestamp>
        </authentication>
        <result>
              <status>success</status>
              <function>readByQuery</function>
              <controlid>testControlId</controlid>
              <data listtype="customer" count="26" totalcount="26" numremaining="0">
                    <customer>
                          <RECORDNO>15</RECORDNO>
                          <CUSTOMERID>RIC001</CUSTOMERID>
                          <NAME>XYZ</NAME>
                          <ENTITY>CRIC001</ENTITY>
                          <PARENTKEY></PARENTKEY>
                          <PARENTID></PARENTID>
                          <PARENTNAME></PARENTNAME>
                       </customer>
                <customer>
                          <RECORDNO>15</RECORDNO>
                          <CUSTOMERID>RIC001</CUSTOMERID>
                          <NAME>BBB</NAME>
                          <ENTITY>CRIC001</ENTITY>
                          <PARENTKEY></PARENTKEY>
                          <PARENTID></PARENTID>
                          <PARENTNAME></PARENTNAME>
                       </customer>
                                      </data>
         </result>
  </operation>
</response>
```

Unmarshall code

```
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
 javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
 Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new    StringReader(response.toString() ) ) );
 System.out.println(customer.getNAME());
```

Comment: I have updated my unmarshalling code in the original post

Comment: You are probably getting a ClassCastException, why don't you include that in your question?
When the string is unmarshalled, it is of the type of the root node. That is ``response``, not ``customer``. You need to navigate through your object tree.

Comment: I need to navigate through the object tree and extract only the customer objects. I need to write some code to get it. I am looking for help in writing that code

Comment: You could try to retrieve the customer node via XPath: `Node node = (Node)xpath.evaluate(xpathExpression, document, XPathConstants.NODE)` where the xpathExpression might be something like `//customer`. You could then convert the Node to a Document via [`Document's importNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29) method or do whatever you whish to do with the node.

Comment: Not sure if you want to achieve something like explained [in this blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html). Note that you are not restricted to StaX but also could use either [`Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Node, Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20java.lang.Class%29) or [`Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Source, Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20java.lang.Class%29)